# Call to a member function store() on null in Laravel 5.5 using postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, storage, postman

I'm testing file upload with Postman but I always get this error. I've already tried adding and removing from the headers in the Postman request the field "multipart/form-data" with no result.

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVLk0.png)

My code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'string|max:255',
        'second_name' => 'string|max:255',
        'description' => 'string|max:255',
        'gender' =>  'string|max:255',
        'admin' =>  'boolean',
        'birthday'  => 'string|max:255',
        'email' => 'string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'min:6|required_with:password_confirmation|same:password_confirmation',
        'file' => 'file',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->second_name = $request->input('second_name');
    $user->description = $request->input('description');
    $user->gender = $request->input('gender');
    $user->admin = $request->input('admin');
    $user->birthday = $request->input('birthday');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->imageUrl = $request->file('file')->store('images');

    if($user->save()) {
        return new $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving an error because the file is not being set properly in your request.

As a result of `$request->file('file')` is returning null, and you are trying to call a method on null, resulting in the exception.

When making a PUT or PATCH request to Laravel using Postman one must take a slightly different approach than usual.

Due to the way Laravel handles PUT and PATCH requests, you will need to send your request in Postman as a POST request, and supply `_method` with value `PUT` in the header. This is what Laravel expects.

If this is a required field, I would also suggest changing the validation rule for a file to the following:

`'file' => 'file|required'`

This will make troubleshooting your API easier. A JSON error response will be provided if the file has not been detected in the request.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm sending it as a body? As a header I'm sending the bearer token. Yes, adding the required field it tells me that 'file' is required so the file is not being detected.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how I misread your screenshot. I have updated my answer. Please try sending your inputs using the x-www-form-urlencoded option in Postman. If you do not specify this option when making a PUT request to your Laravel API, the provided values will not be detected in your request.

Comment: The x-www-form-urlencoded option unlike the form-data option doesn't give me the possibility to upload a file from my computer as the body.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another potential solution

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed the request from put to post and it works now.